# VSCode codeLens Accept Current Change only deletes last conflict marker

Tags: visual-studio-code, codelens

I'm using vscode as the merge tool on ubuntu 20.04. While doing a rebase, I do see the codelens toolbar of which change to accept - but then sometimes instead of accepting the changes it only removes the last conflict marker.

```
<<< HEAD (Current Change)
...
=====
...
>>> Commit (Incoming Change)
```

Turns into:

```
<<< HEAD (Current Change)
...
=====
...
```

Moreover, if I fix this manually and proceed to the next change, it seems to still remove the line that would be that last conflict marker in relation to the new conflict. So if in the first conflict there were 10 lines between <<< HEAD and >>> Commit, then in the next conflict it deletes the 11th line after the new <<< HEAD marker.

It happens quite sporadically, and only on work files that I sadly cannot share, but I hope this is enough information to explain what's going on. I'll be thankful for any help!